# Which AngularJs Material component can be used to show stacked messages with collpase/expand support

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-material

I have to show stacked messages in angularjs application in similar way we show multiple notification on mobile with support of collapse/expand feature.
Need to figure out which angularjs material component will serve this purpose.
Any example link will be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Questions should include more than a request for opinions or help. They need to show that you have put forth some effort, i.e. you've tried these components and couldn't get it to work like you want. Asking for someone to solve a problem for you when you have not demonstrated that you have already done some investigation is discouraged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, AngularJS does not provide Accordion/ExpansionPanels. You need to implement it or use a library with support of customizing (so you can replace `<md-list-item>` with headers or use `whiteFrame`s for content or the whole thing so it fits right in your application theme).

Also AngularJS Material is now stable and they aren't accepting new feature requests. AngularJS itself is in the last part of its Long Term Support (LTS) period.

Comment: If this is the case, is there any Angularjs component which can be used to display stacked mesages (one top of above in stacked manner with expanding and collapsing support).?

Comment: Yep! There are plenty. The UI you are looking for is commonly called `Accordion` or `Expansion Panel`. I just searched `AngularJS Accordion` and found some. Its you to decide which API you'd like.

Comment: One of the reasons that Expansion panels and accordions weren't built into AngularJS Material is that there are technical AngularJS issues that make dealing with the animations very challenging. This was thankfully resolved in Angular and Angular Material has an ExpansionPanel due to this.